# event.dataTransfer is getting undefined in JEST for dragstart

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, lwc-jest

I'm trying to implement Jest tests for a module(to reorder data table rows). However, I'm unable to mimic the `dragstart` event.  Can anyone help me to achieve the same behavior -

Here is the function which is getting called on the `dragstart` -

```js
onDragStart(evt) {
    evt.dataTransfer.setData("dragId", evt.currentTarget.dataset.dragId);
    evt.dataTransfer.setData("sy", evt.pageY );
    evt.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
    evt.currentTarget.classList.add("grabbed");
}
```

Here I'm getting error -
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined` at first line.

Here is the jest method -

```js
it("should check a mouse drag event", () => {
    const element = createElement("c-data-table-draggable", {
      is: DataTableDragable
    });
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    getRecordWireAdapter.emit(mockGetRecord);
    //element.users = mockGetRecord;

    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      expect(element).toBeAccessible();
      
      const trEls = element.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('tr');
      expect(trEls.length).toBeGreaterThan(mockGetRecord.length);
 
      trEls[1].dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("dragstart", { clientX: 0, clientY: 0, pageY : 20 }));      
    });
  });
```

Component HTML for reference -

```html
<template>
  <table
    class="table-dragable slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered"
    aria-describedby="User Details"
  >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Index</th>
        <th scope="col">Salesforce ID</th>
        <th scope="col">User Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Email ID</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <template if:true={users.data}>
        <template for:each={users.data} for:item="user" for:index="index">
          <tr
            class="grabable"
            key={user.Id}
            id={user.Id}
            draggable="true"
            data-drag-id={index}
            ondragstart={onDragStart}
            ondragover={onDragOver}
            ondrop={onDrop}
          >
            <th scope="col" class="myIndex">{index}</th>
            <th scope="col" class="myId">{user.Id}</th>
            <th scope="col">{user.Username}</th>
            <th scope="col">{user.Email}</th>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </template>
      <template if:true={users.error}> No rows found. </template>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div>
    <lightning-button
      variant="brand"
      label="Submit"
      title="Submit"
      onclick={handleSubmit}
      class="slds-m-around_x-large"
    ></lightning-button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jest ships with the [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/9a382982d8ab1f498b4e789fd16d494b1f37ebbb/test/web-platform-tests/to-run.yaml#L376-L382) and you can see that the **dataTransfer** is not yet implemented and hence you are receiving the error below

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined

The undefined here is the [dataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) object.

You can use the jest manual [mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) to mock the implementation of dataTransfer as shown below. Note how I have used the [object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to override the custom event so it has the dataTransfer function and the properties.

The HTML template code is as below

```
<template>
<table
    class="table-dragable slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered"
    aria-describedby="User Details"
>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Index</th>
            <th scope="col">Salesforce ID</th>
            <th scope="col">User Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Email ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <template if:true={users}>
            <template
                for:each={users}
                for:item="user"
                for:index="index"
            >
                <tr
                    class="grabable"
                    key={user.Id}
                    id={user.Id}
                    draggable="true"
                    data-drag-id={index}
                    ondragstart={onDragStart}
                >
                    <th scope="col" class="myIndex">{index}</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="myId">{user.Id}</th>
                    <th scope="col">{user.Username}</th>
                    <th scope="col">{user.Email}</th>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </template>
        <template if:true={error}> No rows found. </template>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div>
    <lightning-button
        variant="brand"
        label="Submit"
        title="Submit"
        onclick={handleSubmit}
        class="slds-var-m-around_x-large"
    ></lightning-button>
</div>
```

__________________________________________________________________________________

The JavaScript code that i have written test is below

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getUserList from '@salesforce/apex/UserController.getUserList';

export default class LwcTest extends LightningElement {

@track
users
@track
error;

@wire(getUserList)
wiredUsers({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.users = data;
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
        this.users = undefined;
    }
}

onDragStart(evt) {
    evt.dataTransfer.setData("dragId", evt.currentTarget.dataset.dragId);
    evt.dataTransfer.setData("sy", evt.pageY );
    evt.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
    evt.currentTarget.classList.add("grabbed");
   }
}
```

---

Here is how the jest code for the above code

```
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import { registerLdsTestWireAdapter } from '@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest';
import LwcTest from 'c/lwcTest';
import getUserList from '@salesforce/apex/UserController.getUserList';

const users = [
 {
    Id: '0050U000004YzSVQA0',
    Username: 'autoproc@00d0u000000gvvruac',
    Email: 'autoproc@00d0u000000gvvruac',
    index: 0
},
{
    Id: '0050U000004YzSaQAK',
    Username: 'automatedclean@00d0u000000gvvruac',
    Email: 'automatedclean@00d0u000000gvvruac',
    index: 1
},
{
    Id: '0050U000004YzSPQA0',
    Username: 'test-ofnikchfgnjt@example.com',
    Email: 'random.email@random.time',
    index: 2
},
{
    Id: '0050U000004YzSUQA0',
    Username: 'integration@00d0u000000gvvruac.com',
    Email: 'integration@example.com',
    index: 3
},
{
    Id: '0050U000004YzSYQA0',
    Username: 'insightssecurity@00d0u000000gvvruac.com',
    Email: 'insightssecurity@example.com',
    index: 4
},
   {
    Id: '0050U000004YzSZQA0',
    Username:
        'chatty.00d0u000000gvvruac.f9lyy22pvr2b@chatter.salesforce.com',
    Email: 'noreply@chatter.salesforce.com',
    index: 5
    }
 ];

  const getRecordWireAdapter = registerLdsTestWireAdapter(getUserList);

  describe('c-lwc-test', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
    // The jsdom instance is shared across test cases in a single file so reset the DOM
    while (document.body.firstChild) {
        document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        // Prevent data saved on mocks from leaking between tests
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    }
});

 it('should check a mouse drag event', () => {
     const element = createElement('c-lwc-test', {
        is: LwcTest
    });
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    getRecordWireAdapter.emit(users);

    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        expect(element).toBeAccessible();

        const trEls = element.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('tr');
        expect(trEls.length).toBeGreaterThan(users.length);
        const dragStartEvt = new CustomEvent('dragstart');
        dragStartEvt.pageY = '1';
        const setData = jest.fn();
        Object.assign(dragStartEvt, {
            dataTransfer: { setData: setData, effectAllowed: 'move' }
        });
        trEls[1].dispatchEvent(dragStartEvt);
        expect(setData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
        expect(setData).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1,'dragId', '0');
        expect(setData).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2,'sy', '1');
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked smooth! :)